# How to use multiple IIFs condition in expression in SSRS Reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, multiple-columns, nested-if

I want to display records in MS SSRs based on multiple IFFs Condition. Any idea? Please help me!

My table is "customers" and columns are "cust1", "cust2", "cust3", "cust4"

```
if(cust1.value!=null)
{
  display cust1;
   if(cust2.value!=null)
    {
     display cust1+","+cust2;
    }
   if(cust3.value!=null)
   {
     diplay cust1+","+cust2+"and+"+cust3
   }
   if(cust4.value!=null)
   {
     diplay cust1+","+cust2+","+cust3+"and"+cust4;
   } 
}else
diplay cust1;
```

I just wrote C# syntax for understand logic. I want to display like result
Ex: for SSRS I tried

```
=First(Fields!cust1.value,"customername")&
IIF(First(Fields!Cust2.value,"customername")+" ">" ",
IIF(First(Fields!Cust3.value,"customername")+" ">" ",
IIF(First(Fields!cust4.value,"customername")+" ">" ",
", "+First(Fields!Cust4.Value,"customername")+
", "+First(Fields!Cust3.Value,"customername")+
", "+First(Fields!Cust2.Value,"customername"),
" and"+First(Fields!cust1.Value,"customername"))," ")," ")
```

but no idea how to implement "cust2", "cust3". Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the IIF expression works.

> **IIF(** CND **,** DWT **,** DWF **)**

- *CND* = The condition that is checked:
  In your example: `Len(First(Fields!cust1.value,"customername")) > 0` (or `IsNothing(First(Fields!cust1.value,"customername"))` but then you need to turn it around)
- *DWT* = What to do/display when *true*. So when the condition is met.
  In your example you wish to display the value.
- *DWF* = What to do/display when *false*. Familiar to the "else" part of an if-block.
  In your example you wish to display nothing or an empty string.

If you actually want to **nest** multiple IIF expressions it is possible by just replacing a *DWT* or *DWF* (or both) with another IIF expression. This can be nested as many times as you desire. Here is a simple example:

> **IIF(** CND1 **,** **IIF(** CND2 **,** DWT2 **,** DWF2 **)** **,** **IIF(** CND3 **,** DWT3 **,** DWF3 **)** **)**
>   *------------------|________DWT1________|---|________DWF1________|---*

However, when applied on your example I don't believe it is necessary to nest. The following expression should give you the desired result:

```
=IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust1.value,"customername")) > 0, First(Fields!cust1.value,"customername") + " ", "") + 
       IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust2.value,"customername")) > 0, First(Fields!cust2.value,"customername") + " ", "") +
       IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust3.value,"customername")) > 0, First(Fields!cust3.value,"customername") + " ", "") + 
       IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust4.value,"customername")) > 0, First(Fields!cust4.value,"customername"), "")
```

Comment: Hi ,Oceans thanks for reply i tried above your expression but it throws some error ...any way to modify my expression (as given above)  like      IIF( CND1 , IIF( CND2 , DWT2 , DWF2 ) , IIF( CND3 , DWT3 , DWF3 ) ).like this condition

Comment: I actually forgot to close a few brackets ")" so I fixed it, try again. What is the error you're receiving? Let's start with a  simple expression like this: `=IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust3.value,"customername")) > 0, First(Fields!cust3.value,"customername"), "")` this might be invalid because of the scope defenition, so next try without the scope definition like this: `=IIF(Len(First(Fields!cust3.value)) > 0, First(Fields!cust3.value) , "" )`