# Nested IIF statement to produce 1 of 3 results

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2, iif

I am trying to piece together a nested "IIF" statement to produce one of three Values but my line is not working

```
=IIF(Fields!LeaseNumber.value = "", "Vacant",Fields!tenantName.value) AND (IIF(Fields!tenantName.Value ="",Fields!LeaseDBA.Value, Fields!tenantName.Value))
```

My expected outcome should be:

If No lease# - "Vacant"

if no tenantName - "LeaseDBA"

all other rows just give me - "tenantname"

All the other questions I reviewed didn't seem to match this type of IIF clause.
Any help really is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually recently just tried to expalain how the IIF expression works and how to nest them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35289515/4579864

To check if a value is null or empty, you're better off using one of these functions:

- You can use `IsNothing()` to check if there is a value. Applied to your example would result to this:

  ```
  =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!LeaseNumber.value)
  ,"Vacant" 
  ,IIF(IsNothing(Fields!tenantName.Value), Fields!LeaseDBA.Value, Fields!tenantName.Value))
  ```
- You can calculate the length of your value with `Len()` and then check if it is larger than 0.

  ```
  =IIF(Len(Fields!LeaseNumber.value) > 0 
  ,IIF(Len(Fields!tenantName.Value) > 0, Fields!tenantName.Value, Fields!LeaseDBA.Value)
  ,"Vacant" )
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was unsure that I had to add the first clause again and then add the results again afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

If No lease# - "Vacant" (If there is no LeaseNumber then show "Vacant" -String only)

If no tenantName - "LeaseDBA" (If there is not tenantName then show `Fields!LeaseDBA.Value`

And for other rows just give me `Fields!tenantName.Value`

If this is you want then try below expression.

```
IIF(Trim(CStr(Fields!LeaseNumber.Value))="","Vacant",CStr(Fields!tenantName.Value)) & IIF(Trim(CStr(Fields!tenantName.Value))="",Fields!LeaseDBA.Value,CStr(Fields!tenantName.Value))
```